# PCI-E speed below expected value checklist

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

In short, my problem is that my GPU reports my pci-e speed as 4x, I'd expect it to be 16x or at the very least 8x.

Here are the things I've tried so far:

1. Ensured the GPU is in the correct PCI-E 16x slot. (The "GPU slot" closest to cpu, for me it's PCIEX16_1)
2. Checked the MOBOs manual to see if that PCI-E slot shares bandwidth with something else, and it shouldn't.
3. Checked with a couple of different programs that the PCI-E speed is indeed 4x rather than the expected 16x (I used GPU-Z and the gpus own software)
4. Checked my PCI-E powersaving settings under windows' powermanagement (they're off so that should be good)
5. Checked the bus speed under load, and it's still 4x so it shouldn't be powersaving anyways. (Ran a game, ensured my GPU got to 99% and vram was nearly fully utilized as well)
6. Checked bios for any PCI-E related settings (I couldn't find any? P8P67-REV3.0)

**What else can I do to troubleshoot this problem?**

(I'm trying to write the question in a generic way that would help as many other people as possible, but here are my specific specs for those interested: P8P67-rev 3.0 mobo, HD Radeon 6790 GPU, slot it is in is PCIe16x_1, software I've tried is Catalyst Control Center, GPU-Z, I'm on Win 10 64-bit. I was thinking of upgrading that HD Radeon to RX 480, which would remove the bottleneck from my system, and shouldn't be able to saturate Pcie 2.0 @ 16x anyways, but before that I wanted to ensure that my 16x is working all proper. It being reported as 4x got me worried.)

Also, could it be that 6970 isn't capable of saturating PCIE 2.0 @ 4x? Could that be it?

Comment: See number #3 ?

Comment: Good call.  Sorry about that.  Did you try the "?" to get GPUz to try and bring the video card out of a low power state.  I do see #4 & 5. but computers are funny.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I actually just found another thing for my list today, took out the GPU, blew some compressed air into the PCIe slot, put the GPU back in and... I got it going x16 now. Can't believe that worked. I'm happy it did work tho.